# Is there a memcached no igbinary support work around for CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, igbinary

Is there a work around for this problem I don't want to use the igbinary for memcached in codeigniter. And I don't want the message to show up anymore because it can't use the igbinary.

However I need to mention that this warning only shows up the first time when the page is loaded when I reload the page it doesn't show up. Isn't that strange? So I'm not really sure the problem lies with the igbinary that isn't installed.

I'm using codeigniter 3.x

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Memcached::get(): could not unserialize value, no igbinary support
Filename: drivers/Cache_memcached.php
Line Number: 50
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, this issue occurred because the `php-igbinary` extension was missing on my Ubuntu server.

To check if the igbinary extension is present in the PHP command line:

```sh
php --ini | grep igbinary
```

In this particular issue above, the PHP code is executed at the web app level. Therefore, the check for the extension needs to be done at the web app level (e.g. fpm).

In any case, to address the issue on my ubuntu server, I had to install the PHP extension:

```sh
sudo apt-get install php-igbinary
```